# In ApplePay.js, need to display an error message on the paysheet

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

Trying to implement ApplePay for Web using ApplePay.js. If the user enters an invalid shipping address, I'd like to highlight an error on the paysheet so that the user has a chance to correct the issue. I see there is an ApplePayError class here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applepayjs/applepayerror, however I have no idea how to utilize this class. I've tried this with no luck:

```
var err = new ApplePayError("shippingContactInvalid", "postalAddress", "Address is invalid");
```

Is this even right? It doesn't display any error on the paysheet so I think it's wrong but I don't know how to do this and I can't seem to find any information about it's usage. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 4):

Ensure version 3 of Apple Pay js api is being used to create the ApplePaySession.

Then pass a result object with status and errors into a 'completion' method:

```
var err = new ApplePayError("shippingContactInvalid", "postalAddress", "Address is invalid");
    session.completePayment({
        status: ApplePaySession.STATUS_FAILURE,
        errors: [ err ]
    });
```